# Update 3 breaks Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

After installing Update 3 for VS13 and restarting my computer, it can't be started. The first try shows me a message:

> EditorPackage cannot be load

, and a few more messages, but with other package names (DesignerPackage, CssPackage...). It navigates me to its log - `ActivityLog.xml`, where I can find messages like this:

```xml
<entry>
<record>1465</record>
<time>2014/08/09 16:23:06.287</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>End package load [DesignerPackage]</description>
<guid>{512BE089-83EC-4CC6-8483-CF16565AE209}</guid>
<hr>80131500</hr>
<errorinfo>No exports were found that match the constraint: 
ContractName    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService
RequiredTypeIdentity    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService</errorinfo>
</entry>
```

Then, it shows black screen and nothing else. So I kill the `devenv.exe` process and try it again, but every next time it only shows white screen and then disappears. The `devenv` process is still running in `taskmgr`.

I found an article on MSDN, where they suggest to run `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`.
I tried it, waited for the devenv process to disappear from task manager and then started VS.
It looked, like it is starting for the first time, but after a while, it started throwing these errors again.

**Edit:**

So, I tried to repair Visual Studio with its repair button in uninstaller. It reinstalled VS successfuly. Then I restarted my computer. Now, when I try to start Visual Studio, it shows the start page (!), but then goes white and it says:

> Visual Studio is not responding

;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache
```

directory (obviously while VS was not running) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Rename %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache directory.

That seems to correct this error message. This seems to correct most VS errors related to extensions.

Comment: Sorry, I've already uninstalled VS2013, so I can't test it. So, anyone, who has the same problem and this solution solved it, please reply on this comment. Then I'll know if I can accept this answer and reward the author.